# Running Python Deamon script inside another script running at run level

Tags: python, operating-system, openwrt

I have specified the stdout as `/tmp/x.log` while running the daemon.

```
def __init__(self, basemac, timeout, command, address, port):
        self.stdin_path = '/dev/null'
        self.stdout_path = '/tmp/deamon.log'
        self.stderr_path = '/tmp/daemon.log'
        self.pidfile_path = '/tmp/apstats_client.pid'
        self.pidfile_timeout = 5
```

I am trying to run this script as `./apstats.py` start inside another run-level script with run-level as 99.

When i do a `tail -f /tmp/daemon.log` ( on the hardware where we are testing this), I see the stdout gets flushed after sometime. Does anybody know the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

Python output is buffered. On console it syncs with terminal. For writing logs i suggest to use `logging` module.

You can run python with `python -u`. Then stdout will flush each write.

Comment: confirm as solution ;)